# Is this way of shared resource thread-safe?

Tags: python, multithreading, thread-safety, locking, python-multithreading

In my current Python project I have such structure:

- file A has a `Meta` class which stores some global resources, such as a global DB access (`Meta.db`)
- file B has many classes, each class calls the global DB access `Meta.db` to access the database

Here comes the problem:

- in file C, there is a function spawns around 20 threads (no lock, as no global resource are shared directly by threads), each thread calls different classes in file B, to manipulate database for different purposes, like this:

  1. file C spawns 20 threads ---->
  2. each thread call classes in file B ---->
  3. each class call `Meta.db`, the global single DB access

The program runs with no errors, but very high in context switching (99% of runtime), therefore I would like to know whether this way of implementation is practical? or thread-safe?

Comment: First, almost every operations in modern DB server is thread-safe. Just imagine there are 20 different users instead of threads. Second, maybe you can consider to reconstruct your file C as does it really need to spawns 20 threads? Or using asyncio?

Comment: @Sraw Hi Sraw, thanks for the reply! I tried `process` in file C to try to avoid context switching with a pool in size of 4, but it turns out that for each process the global DB access `Meta.db` in file B, imported from file A, becomes `None`, do you have some ideas about this? Thanks!